# GWMI Win32_Process query

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to determine with Powershell where a process is being ran from. The following will work if the process is running on C but not on any other drive. So if I have multiple drives that a process is running on, I get the result of no data:

```
gwmi Win32_Process | ? { $_.commandline -match "svchost" } | ft commandline.processid
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `ft commandline.processid` is not valid. I think you mean `ft CommandLine,ProcessId` (i.e., `,`, not `.`).

Comment: Also, processes do not run on drives. They run in memory. They may access files on drives. Files from drives are used to create the process in memory. But the process itself does not run "on" a drive. The `.commandline` property will tell you the file that was used to create the process.

Comment: Plus, unless you have windows installed on a drive other than C:, I'm not sure how a svchost could be running from anywhere other than c:\windows\system32.

Comment: [The frustration of people who are not interested in why something works but only interested in the magic phrase they need to type](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090416-00/?p=18543)